# Checkbox is always returning true, even when not checked

Tags: php

```
<input name="inform_me" id="inform_me" type="checkbox"> inform me
```

Whenever I check if this checkbox is set, I get

> bool(true)

even if the checkbox is not really checked.

This is how my PHP looks like:

```
var_dump(isset($_POST['inform_me']));
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Isset checks if something is there or not. You are not checking if checkbox is checked but if checkbox exist.

Comment: Did you try to get its value from the javascript console in the browser before submitting the form? Remember the value you're trying to get is the $_POST['inform_me'], isset only checks if the POSTED form brings that field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. My problem was that I passed the variable `$_POST['inform_me']` with Ajax. In Ajax I used `data: { inform_me: $('#inform_me').val() }` to get the value of the checkbox. Instead of `.val()` I am using `.is(':checked')` now and it works!

Answer (score 5):

The [PHP isset()](http://php.net/isset) function will check if the variable exists!

For example.

```
$a = false; // or any other value
echo isset($a); // True, because the variable $a exists!
echo isset($b); // False, because the variable $b doesn't exist!
```

No need to put the isset there, try the following:

```
echo $_POST['inform_me'];
```

The `$_POST['inform_me']` variable will contain the value.
If it is checked, it will contain the value that is the **value of your checkbox**.

For example this is the HTML code

```
<input name="inform_me" id="inform_me" type="checkbox" value="test"> inform me </input>
```

Then the variable $_POST['inform_me'] will be "test" if checked, otherwise (if unchecked) the value will be an empty string.

In case you didn't provide the HTML tag with a value, the variable will be "on" if checked, otherwise an empty string (if unchecked).

Comment: @HasseBjörk This depends on your code. It will take the value attribute of the checkbox if checked. Otherwise it'll be an empty string.

Comment: Thank you! If value attribute is not set, it will return "on" or empty string if unchecked!

Comment: @HasseBjörk Right! Added that into my answer.

Comment: My problem was in the Ajax code. I have posted the answer below. Thanks for your answer, you are absolutely right though.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know in my short experience checkbox return on or off (so as you take it it will always return true because it exist but you're not especifing the return conditioned to the value it have), as said before. Even so, there is a way I have successfully used to condition that, in my page I have a checkbox for input if you want RSS or not and I store 1 if the want RSS (mode on) or 0 if the don't. Being for your case like this:

```
($_POST['inform_me'] == 'on') ? 1 : 0;
```

So far you can change one and 0 to whatever return you want to get back, remembering that the first one (1 in these case) will be the return if condition is true and the second (0 for the example) if condition is false.

Comment: on is not a constant, but a string. It should be "on". I don't think the "off" value exists, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Actually you are right and I have already edited to correct that, thanks a lot.